# Delete object on click

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a todo app, I have a form with a table where the user can add "todo" to this form.

I would like to be able to delete the added "todo" from database by clicking on a button without having to redirect the user to another page, is there any way to do this with Django?

http://postimg.org/image/8dpe1dcob/

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your views here.

def tasks_list(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.created_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            #return render(request, 'todo/tasks_list.html', {'tasks': tasks, 'form': form})
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render(request, 'todo/tasks_list.html', {'tasks': tasks, 'form': form})




def post_remove(request, new_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Task, id=new_id)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('todo.views.tasks_list')
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.tasks_list, name='tasks_list'),
    #url(r'^$', views.tasks_list, name='post_remove'),
]
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add todo'}), label='')
    due_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add due date', 'class':'datepicker'}), label='')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'due_date',)
```

template/task_list.html

```
{% extends 'todo/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Todos</h1>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="textField" placeholder="Add tasks">-->
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" >{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|bootstrap }}

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="plusSign">Go!</button>
      </span>
      </form>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
  <table style="width:100%" id='todoTable'>
    <thead id="tableHead">
      <tr>
        <td>Todo</td>
        <td>due date</td>
        <td>delete</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
      <td> {{ task.due_date }} </td>
      <td> <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'tasks_list' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> </td>
    </tr>
  </body>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit:

I found a solution using the code from the Django girls tutorial.

I have added the following code:

Views.py

```
def post_remove(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Url.py

```
url(r'^task/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
```

templates/task_list.html

```
<td> <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=task.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
```

Could anyone check if my understand of the deletion is correct?

So the `task_list.html` is adding a link with the primary key to each todo as `href="/task/49/remove/"` which allows the post_remove function in `views.py` to remove only the "todo" with the specific href and the removal only works when the button is clicked because of the request parameter at the post_remove function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using ajax, with a simple call to your delete view, you can hit the database and delete the entry. Just remove it client-side with javascript.

Or you could consider using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) with [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) for instance, so as to not reinvent the wheel and add some flexibility to further improve your app. You can add callbacks to ensure that everything went right server-side.

If you want to be on the bleeding edge, you can check out [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks correct, but it *will* redirect the user to the `'/'` url when you click the link. Wasn't your question directly aimed at deleting a `Task` with no page reload?